# Error: authentication needed: password or unlock when deploying a contract with truffle

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment, truffle-config

i am using angular with truffle. I am trying to deploy a contract through truffle migrate. here is my 2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var contractFacotry = artifacts.require('./contractFactory.sol');

module.exports = function(deployer, accounts) {
deployer.deploy(contractFacotry), {
from: accounts[accounts.length-1]
};
};
```

and i have unlocked this account as well in truffle console.here is it's ss
[image]

but when i migrate with truffle migrate i am getting following error
[image]

any idea what's wrong here?

**UPDATE**

My 1_initial_migration.js is following

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

and Migrations.sol is following

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  function Migrations() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) restricted public {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) restricted public {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you're running into a timeout with your unlock. If I remember it correctly, it has a default of 5min. If you unlock and immediately call migrate, is it working then? you can also specify a third parameter for the unlock function. 0 = no timeout.

Comment: @ivicaa i have tried calling immediately after inlocking the account, but getting same error. plus calling with third argument zero also does not make any difference